# Alfresco Community Edition, ManifoldCF and Elasticsearch to optimize full-text search

Tags: oracle, elasticsearch, alfresco, cmis, manifoldcf

How can I integrate a milions documents Alfresco Community Edition CMIS repository and an Oracle RDBMS repository that stores metadata of the same documents, trough Apache ManifoldCF to index composed metadata in Elasticsearch to build clustered indexes and so optimize full-text search?

I'm following [this](http://www.massnerder.io/alfresco/2013/8/13/alfresco-apache-manifoldcf-elasticsearch) tutorial for now. But I'm not so sure this is the better way to do.

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

ManifoldCF can definitely be used to do this, but it is not clear from your post what problem or question you are having with that approach. There are many other ways to accomplish this. They all have trade-offs to consider.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
I need to improve the performance of full-text search for an existing Alfresco / Solr document repository of 9 million nodes.
The Solr indices of the Alfresco community version appear to be not clusterizable.
At this point I will add Elasticsearch indices built with the documents injected by ManifoldCF.
Unlike the tutorial I linked, it was easier for me to work with the Kibana user interface that I added to Elasticsearch.